# First order by importance then group by section

Tags: mariadb, group-by, order-by, greatest-n-per-group

In this table scheme http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/101a9c/9/0

```
id  section     rev     importance
2   1           b       6
1   1           a       5
3   2           c       9
5   3           e       6
4   3           d       5
```

i want to `order by **importance**` then `group by **section**`

so i tried to use `GROUP BY docs.section`

```
SELECT docs.id, docs.section, docs.rev, (
  SELECT SUM(docs_importance.importance) 
  FROM docs_importance
  WHERE docs_importance.doc_id = docs.id
) AS importance
FROM docs
GROUP BY docs.section    ---GROUPING
ORDER BY docs.section, importance DESC
```

but got this result:

```
id  section     rev     importance
1   1           a       5
3   2           c       9
4   3           d       5
```

but the result i want is supposed to be

```
id  section     rev     importance
2   1           b       6
3   2           c       9
5   3           e       6
```

Comment: Follow the `greatest-n-per-group` tag -- it leads to several solutions.  You cannot do your task with a simple `GROUP BY`.  (Meanwhile, the `ORDER BY` is a red herring and could be ignored.)

Answer (score 1):

i used this query

```
SELECT t.id, t.section, t.rev, t.importance FROM (
   SELECT docs.id, docs.section, docs.rev, (SELECT SUM(docs_importance.importance) FROM docs_importance WHERE docs_importance.doc_id = docs.id) AS importance
   FROM docs
   GROUP BY docs.id
   ORDER BY importance DESC
) AS t
GROUP BY t.section
```

where i first made a subquery as a temporary table then ordered it by importance then grouped the outer query by section to get the final result.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can't do what you're thinking you want to do.

Let me put it this way: if you want to "order by importance first, then group by section", tell me how you plan to group the rows for `section = 1` when one row has `importance = 5` and the other has `importance = 6`?

Do you see the problem? It makes no sense. How can I order all the `importance = 6` first, and then somehow group by rows that you've split apart because of your ordering (ie. where `section = 1`)?

This is probably why the SQL syntax requires your `group by` clause first, and your `order by` clause second - because grouping happens first, and ordering happens second.

Interestingly, you noted that you tried this SQL:

```
SELECT docs.id, docs.section, docs.rev, (
  SELECT SUM(docs_importance.importance) 
  FROM docs_importance
  WHERE docs_importance.doc_id = docs.id
) AS importance
FROM docs
GROUP BY docs.section    ---GROUPING
ORDER BY docs.section, importance DESC
```

... but when I paste this into your Fiddle and run, I get an error:

`Unknown column 'GROUPING' in 'group statement'`

Perhaps check on exactly how you got the results you gave?

Comment: the part of `---GROUPING` is supposedly a comment i used --- since it grayed the text.

Comment: Sorry, yes, that error was trivial and I was out of time to look in detail. What I expected was an error because you are selecting columns (`id`, `rev`) that are not contained in your `group by` clause - how should the DMBS pick values? I was surprised to learn MySQL allows this. Other DMBSes don't. See this answer elsewhere for a discussion on this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/24257983/3714936

Comment: Need space after `--` to avoid the error message.